# Find by key in any location of JSONB field

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I have a Postgres table with the JSOB field.

Content example of *body* field

```
{
 "name": "example name",
 "text": "example text",
 "story":
  {
    "id":"UUID1"
  },
 "reference":
  {
   "type":"URI",
   "content":
    {
     "id":"UUID2"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to find documents by ID, but they can be in any place.

The only thing I found till now is

```
 @Repository
 public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<EntityWithJsonbField, String>{
 ...
   Query(value="SELECT * FROM table_with_jsonb_field WHERE body ->> 'id' = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
   List<EntityWithJsonbField> findAllWithId(@Param("id")String id);
...
}
```

but it is searching only by *id* in the root of the document.

Also tried '$..id' (JSON PATH) instead of 'id' with no luck.

Is it even possible?

PS later, I will need to update found content. So, any links to relevant documentation are welcome. :)

**Update:**
Thanks to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113503?noredirect=1) it is working now!

```
 @Repository
 public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<EntityWithJsonbField, String>{
 ...
   Query(value="SELECT * FROM content_type WHERE body @@ cast(concat('$.**.id == \"',:id,'\"') as jsonpath)", nativeQuery = true)
   List<EntityWithJsonbField> findAllWithId(@Param("id")String id);
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain SQL this can be done like this:

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_field @@ '$.**.id == "UUID2"';
```

The expression `$.**.id` iterates recursively through all object keys and matches the key `id` with the value `UUID2`.

However the comparison value for that expression can not be passed as a parameter directly. So you need to concatenate create a string in SQL by passing a (JPA) parameter and then cast that string to a `jsonpath`

```java
"select from the_table  " +
"where jsonb_field @@ concat('$.**.id == \"',:id,'\"')::jsonpath"
```

If your obfuscation layer chokes on the `::` you can use:

```java
"where jsonb_field @@ cast(concat('$.**.id == \"',:id,'\"') as jsonpath)"
```

I have only tested this with plain JDBC, not with JPA, but as the `:id` is not contained inside a SQL string (only inside the Java String), this should work with JPA.

Another option is to use `jsonb_path_exists()` instead, which is easier to use if parameters should be passed into the JSON path expression:

```java
"select from the_table  " +
"where jsonb_path_exists(jsonb_field, '$.**.id ? (@ == $id)', jsonb_build_object('id', :id))"
```

However, `jsonb_path_exists()` can't use an index on the column `jsonb_field`

Comment: Thank you!  @Query(value="SELECT * FROM content_type WHERE body @@ cast(concat('$.**.id == \"',:id,'\"') as jsonpath)", nativeQuery = true) made a trick

Comment: One more question: can I also update JSONB field: add an extra object next to found "id"?